# Tkinter not responding while selenium is working

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, tkinter

I know that this happens because they work on the same thread,but I don't have any clue how to use threading on my project [(here)](https://github.com/SadLandscape/test). Please if you want to edit code I know there are some potentially error-makers but I want to fix them later myself I only need threading for now... (main code is window.py)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Threading is pretty simple! Try this.

```py
import threading

# -- your code --

selenium_thread = threading.Thread(target=function_that_uses_selenium, args=(selenium_func_args,))
tkinter_thread = threading.Thread(target=function_that_uses_tkinter, args=(tkinter_func_args,))

selenium_thread.start()
tkinter_thread.start()
```

Comment: can I use multiple functions as I use tkinter and selenium in multiple functions or I should make as much threads as my functions are?

Comment: Try making one function for each main thread of control. Functions running in threads can call other functions, so try to make the one function that calls all the other helper functions a thread.

Comment: @acw1668 good suggestion! You can create a thread only for the selenium function, the flow will return to the program after you start the thread. After you call the selenium_thread.start(), call tk.mainloop() and your program will continue.

Comment: Thank you I'll try

Comment: On some platforms tkinter must be in the main thread. I think that's true for OSX, not sure about windows and Linux.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm not sure. I'm on OSX now, so I'll test it.

Comment: @enbyte I've got an error here I have two file backend.py and main.py, backend is selenium functions and is imported in main.py main.py is UI, main problem is I made a function which contains all selenium functions but when I run it it says that selenium functions are not defined is there any way to make window respond? Thanks guys

Comment: @acw1668 I've got an error here I have two file backend.py and main.py, backend is selenium functions and is imported in main.py main.py is UI, main problem is I made a function which contains all selenium functions but when I run it it says that selenium functions are not defined is there any way to make window respond? Thanks guys

Comment: @BryanOakley You are correct! Running in the non-mainloop crashes with a `TclError`

Comment: @JokeGamer could you post your error please? (perhaps try `from x import *` instead of just `import x`)

Comment: @JokeGamer Ok. Try `selenium_module.func` instead of `func`.

Comment: @enbyte That's was how I was using it code is in github

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233181/discussion-between-enbyte-and-jokegamer).

Comment: @enbyte are you still here?